# Are HTTP responses to the same resource returned in sequence?

Tags: http, networking, tcp

Say I want to request some resource on a given domain, e.g. example.com/image.jpg.

If I do two requests to this particular resource, can I expect the first response I get back to be mappable to the first response I sent, and so on (or does this depend on client/server implementation)?

I'm asking because if I want to debug request-response pair, I necessarily need to know exactly which response belongs to which request (for timing purposes etc.). So, are there any sure-fire ways to achieve this mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are talking about HTTP/1.x using persistent connections (i.e. HTTP keep-alive) when sending a new request without having the response for the previous one yet, i.e. using [HTTP pipelining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining). In this case the order of the responses matches the order of the requests.

If you are instead talking about HTTP/2 then the situation is different because multiple requests can receive the responses in parallel inside the same TCP connection and this also means that a later requests might have received a response before earlier requests. And in which order requests to the same resource are handled by the server depends fully on the server implementation.

The same is true when the requests are done within independent TCP connections.  The order might be even more unpredictable than with HTTP/2 because the requests might be handled in different threads or processes and thus the order also depends on the scheduling of these in the operating system.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your input Steffen. So I guess the answer to this is no, there is no sure-fire way of mapping the correct responses to requests since connections will be made to servers which I don't directly control.

Comment: @ØyvindHauge: of course you can map each response to the request. You can do this based on the number of the request inside a persistent HTTP connection which matches the number of the response. If you have different TCP connections the response will always be in the TCP connection of the request. And with HTTP/2 you have clear associations between a response and a request too. The only thing is that the order of responses is not necessarily the order of requests if you have multiple TCP connections or HTTP/2 but you can still associate each response with a specific request.

Comment: Ah, ok. I'll do some more research. So I guess my handling of this needs to happen in the transport layer? @SteffenUllrich

Comment: @ØyvindHauge: Both at the transport layer (i.e. which TCP connection) and the application layer (order inside the same connection in case of HTTP keep-alive).